# Как из нескольких цветов сделать заливку фона?

Tags: html, css, css3

[image: Вот подобие такого фона я хочу получить]

Вот подобие такого фона я хочу получить.
Здесь, похоже разделение по центру и в обе стороны идет градиент. Но как это сделать, не понимаю.

Comment: Не нужно понимать. Если это css (что вряд ли) то просто смотрите исходники и повторяете. Но в данном случае скорее всего это картинка

Comment: вот ссылка там используется 4 цвета для фона https://dribbble.com/shots/580608-Login

Comment: по ссылке дизайн и скриншот, это не html ниразу

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Прямо вот так вряд ли получится, проще картинкой резиновой.
Но что-то близкое попробуйте соорудить. Вот вам конструктор: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Comment: Скорей всего, вы правы, лучше картинкой

Answer (score 0):

Похоже на радиальный градиент http://htmlbook.ru/css3-na-primerakh/radialnyi-gradient

Comment: нет, радиальный не подходит, попробовал

Comment: Тогда это изображение